# Linux iostat "averaged" result over a period of time

Tags: linux, performance-testing, iostat

I am using the iostat utility on my RedHat Linux server to monitor the performance of a disk.  When I use "**iostat -xd sdh 1**", I get the perf result printed every one second.  When I use "**iostat -xd sdh 5**", I get the perf result printed every five second.  My feeling is the latter command is printing a snapshot of the perf every five second, rather than averaging over the past 5 seconds.  Am I correct in my understanding?

If so, is there a way I can make iostat print the perf. number averaged over n seconds, or is there some other utility that will do that.

Currently, the perf number is fluctuating within  a range, and I want to get a somewhat "stable" number.  I am hoping that averaging over a period of time will give me such a number.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure each report is the average since the previous report, not instantaneous.

Comment: This might be an overkill, but sar collects a lot of performance data. https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar

Comment: @UncleCarl  sar has the same options (interval and count) as iostat.  Same question applies to sar as well, when displaying perf stat every  n seconds, is the number the average over the past n seconds or snapshot (value read from proc fs entry).?

Answer (score 0):

From `man 1 iostat`:

`Each subsequent report covers the time since the previous report.` Also, units in the column headers show that numbers usually are **per-second rates**.

Mind the `-y` option and the first output being `statistics concerning the time since the system was booted` if it is not passed.